# Regex in JS which contains special word find result just in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to find result in quotes which contains special word (special key) and delete it.
Online example: https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/1

For example in text find quotes and if it contains "specialkey" match (delete in future with replace) everything in quotes.
In example lines with different cases, so it should match just in lines 1,2,3 but not match in line 4 and 5.
If special word connect with another symbols it should be ignored.

Comment: `"[^"]*specialkey[^"]*"`?

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/2 . @Rawing you need to use capturing group.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with _"If special word connect with another symbols it should be ignored"_, could you give an example where the special word should be ignored?

Comment: As well I'm wondering whether the `"` can be escaped in your scenarios? For instance: `"Here's the \"specialkey\" that should match"` versus `"Here's the ", specialkey, " that shouldn't match"`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Step by step I will understand regexps.